# Double.Parse for Native language support

Tags: c#, parsing, regional-settings

I have a value `20,55` which is in German language.
When I change the regional settings to US the value gets displayed as `2055.0` after running this code:

```
double d = Double.Parse("20,55",CultureInfo.CurrentCUCulture);
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US, the decimal separator is `.`, not `,`. If you attempt to parse `20,55`, it will (apparently) ignore the commas as standard triplet separators (such as in `1,234,567.89`), even though there aren't three digits in all of them.

If you want to parse a Euro-style number, you need to parse it with a Euro-style culture setting.

Answer (score 4):

Because in US the `,` is the thousand separator and it's ignored? In the same way that in Germany (and continental Europe) the `.` is the thousand separator and it's ignored?

In Germany you write: 1.000,55. In USA you write: 1,000.55 (and there are some schools of thought that remove the `,` if there is a single digit before. So 1000.55 and 11,000.55).

Now, if you want to be sure your program is using the `de-DE` culture, pass as a parameter everywhere

```
CurrentCulture culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

double d = double.Parse("20,55", culture);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the US decimal separator is the `.` and not the `,`.

If you want to avoid that problem no matter the regional settings of the user, you could write a extension method:

```
public static String ToRegionalNumber(this String str) {
    String regionalNb = str.Replace(",", NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator);
    regionalNb = regionalNb .Replace(".", NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator);
    return regionalNb ;
}
```

And call this method when working with your number:

```
double d = Double.Parse("20,55".ToRegionalNumber());
```